# Awk, little endian order and 4 hex digits

Tags: awk, hex, decimal, gawk, endianness

I suppose that I have a decimal number, e.g., 97254 ---> 00017BE6 (hex value) using:

```
echo "" | awk '{printf("%08X", 97254)}'
```

Now, if I want to convert hex number (00017BE6, in this case) into 4 numbers of 2 digits (max 8 numbers in input) in little endian order and CSV format, i.e. (**target**):

```
E6,7B,01,00
```

**using only** Awk (a function ad-hoc and return value, for example), how to do?

With:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=7;i=i+2) array[i]=substr($1,i,2)} END{for(a in array) print array[a]}'
```

I have:

```
00
01
7B
E6
```

Using:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=7;i=i+2) array[i]=substr($1,i,2)} END{for(a in array) print array[a]}' ORS=","
```

I have:

```
00,01,7B,E6,
```

but how to remove last comma e convert it in little endian order?

How do I go about this?

Any ideas?

Comment: At the top you ask for `E6,7B,01,00` as the desired output, which is consistent with the _little_ endianness mentioned in the title; at the bottom you ask about removing the trailing `,` from `00,01,7B,E6,` which implies _big_ endianness - which do you want?

Comment: Please note that using `for(a in array)` will _not_ enumerate the array indices in numerical order, because all arrays in `awk` are _associative_ arrays, and enumeration happens unpredictably by the internal _hash_ values of the indices (keys). For arrays with numerical keys, use `for (i=1; i<=length(array); ++i)`.

Comment: Well, thank you for you advice. It had entirely slipped my mind!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo 00017BE6 | awk '{for (i=7;i>=1;i=i-2) printf "%s%s",substr($1,i,2),(i>1?",":"\n")}'
E6,7B,01,00
```

Using `sprintf`, we can start with the decimal number:

```
$ echo 97254 | awk '{hex=sprintf("%08X",$1); for (i=7;i>=1;i=i-2) printf "%s%s",substr(hex,i,2),(i>1?",":"\n");}'
E6,7B,01,00
```

#### How it works

- `for (i=7;i>=1;i=i-2)`

  This starts a loop over index `i` in which we count *down* from 7 to 1.
- `printf "%s%s",substr($1,i,2),(i>1?",":"\n")`

  This prints the desired substring followed by a comma or a newline.  The construct `i>1?",":"\n"` is awk's form of a ternary statement.  It returns `,` if `i>1` or a newline otherwise.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but `sprintf` should work on most `awk`.  It work at least on my old `busybox awk` `BusyBox v1.19.4 `

Comment: @Jotne Thanks for that.  I just checked and [`sprintf` is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_13).  I updated the answer to remove the equivocation.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked for an `awk` command, but consider this generic `bash` function, which uses `printf`, `sed`, and `tac` / `tail -r` internally, and works on both BSD (including OSX) and Linux systems:

```
# SYNOPSIS
#   toHexBytes num [numBytes [littleEndian]]
# DESCRIPTION
#   Prints the bytes that num is composed of in hex. format separated by commas.
#   NUM can be in decimal, hexadecimal, or octal format.
#   NUMBYTES specifies the minimum number of *bytes* to output - defaults to *4*.
#   Specify 0 to only output as many bytes as needed to represent NUM, '' to 
#   represent the default when also specifying LITTLEENDIAN.
#   By default, the bytes are printed in BIG-endian order; if LITTLEENDIAN is nonzero,
#   the bytes are printed in LITTLE-endian order.
# PLATFORM SUPPORT
#   BSD and Linux platforms
# EXAMPLES
#   toHexBytes 256      # -> '00,00,01,00'
#   toHexBytes 256 '' 1 # -> '00,01,00,00'
#   toHexBytes 0x100 0  # -> '01,00'
toHexBytes() {
  local numIn=$1 numBytes=${2:-4} littleEndian=${3:-0} numHex revCmd 
  # Convert to hex.
  printf -v numHex '%X' "$numIn"
  # Determine number of 0s that must be prepended.
  padCount=$(( numBytes * 2 - ${#numHex} ))
  (( padCount < 0 && ${#numHex} % 2 )) && padCount=1
  # Apply 0-padding, if needed.
  (( padCount )) && printf -v numHex "%0$(( padCount + ${#numHex} ))X" "0x$numHex" 
  if (( $littleEndian )); then # LITTLE-endianness
    # Determine command to use for reversing lines.
    [[ $(command -v tac) ]] && revCmd='tac' || revCmd='tail -r'
    # Insert a newline after every 2 digits, except for the last,
    # then reverse the resulting lines,
    # then read all resulting lines and replace all but the last newline
    # with ','.
    sed 's/../&\'$'\n''/g; s/\n$//' <<<"$numHex" | 
      $revCmd |
        sed -e ':a' -e '$!{N;ba' -e '}; s/\n/,/g'
  else # BIG-endianness
    # Insert ',' after every 2 digits, except for the last pair.
    sed 's/../&,/g; s/,$//' <<<"$numHex"
  fi
}
```

Applied to your example number:

```
$ toHexBytes 97254 4 1 # 4 bytes, LITTLE-endian
E6,7B,01,00

$ toHexBytes 97254 # 4 bytes, BIG-endian
00,01,7B,E6
```